# enable button after actual input entered

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How  to enabled button, when the actual amount entered

lets say i have 100 minimum and 200 maximum

i want when user enters amount below 100 error comes actual amount needed and button reamins dsiabled

when user enters more than 200 do the same echo error

user has to enter 100 and above but not exceed maximum

```
 <form method="post">
<input type="text" id="Textfield">
<button type="submit" class="disabledButton" disabled>Submit</button>
<p id="error"></p>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$('#Textfield').keyup(function(){
     var textBox = $('#Textfield').val();
     if((textBox >= 100) || (textBox <= 200) ){
       $('.disabledButton').prop("disabled", false);
     } else {
     $('#error').text('actual amount needed');
        return false;
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of reasons your code is not working:

- `.val()` is *always* text, so you are (would be) comparing "15" with 100 and 200 and it would pass, convert to an integer
- you start with the button disabled, then (assuming everything else is working ok) you enable it, but never disable it again if the value changes again
- same for the #error text, you don't clear it when the value is valid

The main issue is:

```
if((textBox >= 100) || (textBox <= 200) ){
```

if the textbox value is greater than 100 **OR** it's less than 200, well, *all values* follow this rule: eg 1 is less than 200, so passes, 3000 is more than 100, so passes.

This should be

```
if((textBox >= 100) && (textBox <= 200) ){
```

Giving updated snippet:

```js
$('#Textfield').keyup(function() {
  var textBox = $('#Textfield').val() * 1;
  if ((textBox >= 100) && (textBox <= 200)) {
    $('.disabledButton').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#error').text('ok');
  } else {
    $('.disabledButton').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#error').text('actual amount needed');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post">
  <input type="text" id="Textfield">
  <button type="submit" class="disabledButton" disabled>Submit</button>
  <p id="error"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using html 5, you don't need JavaScript. The best way to do this is to set this field to a number, like

```
<input type="number" min="100" max="200" placeholder="value in 100-200" id="Textfield" />
```

By setting min and max values, the form will not submit if the value in this field is not in that range

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#Textfield').on('keyup',function(){
 //every time a key is pressed we count the total number of characters in the field
  var charLength = $(this).val().length;
  //if they are equal to or above 100 and equal to or below 200 we disable the disabled button property else we disable the button again
  if(charLength >= 100 && charLength <= 200){
    $('.disabledButton').prop('disabled',false)
  }else{
    $('.disabledButton').prop('disabled',true)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" id="Textfield">
<button type="submit" class="disabledButton" disabled>Submit</button>
<p id="error"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**
Sorry, I guess I kinda just glossed over the question. Here's your working code))

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" />
    <button type="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
    <p id="error" style="color: red"></p>
</form>

<script>
    const input = document.querySelector('input');
    const button = document.querySelector('button');
    const error = document.querySelector('#error');
    const minVal = 100;
    const maxVal = 200;

    const setError = (current) => {
        const message = `Please enter between ${minVal} and ${maxVal}. You entered ${current}`;
        error.innerText = message;
        error.style.display = 'block';
    };

    const hideError = () => {
        error.style.display = 'none';
    };

    input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
        const enteredValue = parseInt(input.value, 10);

        if (enteredValue >= minVal && enteredValue <= maxVal) {
            button.disabled = false;
            return hideError();
        }

        setError(enteredValue);
        button.disabled = true;
    });
</script>
```

previous edit: Edited to add dynamic error message

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" max="200" />
    <button type="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
    <p id="error" style="color: red"></p>
</form>

<script>
    const input = document.querySelector('input');
    const button = document.querySelector('button');
    const error = document.querySelector('#error');
    const minChars = 10;

    const setError = (length) => {
        const message = `Please enter ${minChars - length} more character(s).`;
        error.innerText = message;
        error.style.display = 'block';
    };

    const hideError = () => {
        error.style.display = 'none';
    };

    input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
        const enteredLength = input.value.length;

        if (enteredLength >= minChars) {
            button.disabled = false;
            return hideError();
        }

        setError(enteredLength);
        button.disabled = true;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You seem to have missed the requirement - compare *value* not *length of value*

Comment: please check your code, and my question description: you code is outputting something different because when u enter 180 and the max is 200, button still disbaled, first debug and run the code by urself to see

Comment: @SherryBacker it's not that it doesn't work, it's that it does something different